"Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment." when submitting an edit with an edit comment
When editing this question by replacing the supplied images of the formula with identical mathjax formulas I tried to supply a reason as shown in the image with "use mathjax instead of images". However that edit reason was declined by the system with a message of

Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment."


I actually tried a few variations of the shown comment, but none was satisfactorily until I deleted the edit reason and left it blank.
This happens identically here on SO meta where I cannot fill-in any edit reason whatsoever.
Giving an edit reason is not mandatory, but might sometimes be desirable. However I wonder whether I miss here something?
If not, I'd like to suggest to change this check so that usual reasons can be given and differentiate system reasons (if needed) differently.
Lol. And after reviewing, when posting this very question in astronomy meta or here in meta, I get repeatedly a 404 when hitting the "post question" button. Something seems to be fishy right now.

Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400923/comment-reserved-for-system-use-when-trying-to-edit-with-an-edit-summary

Ok, sorry for the dupe (though that's obviously not mine). Every time I posted this question on meta here or on astronomy meta, I ended up at a 404 when posting the question

It's not big a problem, I'm just linking them together since this is a problem on all of SE right now apparently.

Since my comment is gone with the duplicate question: Can you please [edit] this question to clarify whether this occurs on SO as well? Showing an error from astronomy SE with a message that may have specific meaning on astronomy SE but not SO isn't really clearcut.

This happens on SO too, @MisterMiyagi.  I ran into it, and came here (MSO) first to find out whether it was a known problem (it was), and then went to the MSE following the cross-site duplicate link.  I've done quite a lot of up-voting.  I also ran into the 300-character limit when cleaning an ancient question — Was the minimum character limit for questions increased to 300 recently? — more up-votes.  That is nominally fixed now!

Happening for me too right now. Can't edit any posts. Desktop Browser

The workaround seems to be to submit without any comment. (That clearly sucks, but a workaround exists.)

@tripleee workaround only for users with full edit privilege. If a user is suggesting an edit, they are forced to fill in an edit reason and then cannot submit that suggestion.

I also found if I closed and re-opened my browser (Chrome on Windows) I could complete an edit. That may be useful to know, if very inconvenient, for those who have a min comment length limit.

Out of curiosity, what sense does it make for any comment text to be "reserved for system use"?

This has happened to me as well. And I swore that this was not the case in the past since I was able to provide reasons for changes for tracking purposes.

This also affects tag wiki edits.

Fixed on MSE

@Slate It's still happening on SO.

@tripleee maybe messages that would be generated by the community user or something.

@Gimby I can imagine that something like that was what they thought they needed, but without any concretion, it seems like a thoroughly stupid idea. What could the community user say which I could not also legitimately need to say? "I am the Communtity user" might come close, but even that is obviously a lie when your user ID is plainly visible next to it.

@tripleee I was more thinking along the lines of "closed/deleted by community" or something along those lines, just boring system messages. Something broke which made the system treat messages that are not system messages AS system messages, that's for sure. We've seen a few pretty sloppy mistakes being corrected quickly the last few days so something is being cooked up. Another experiment, perhaps.
